# Scraping data from web canvas with python

Tags: python, html, canvas, web-scraping

Anyone knows how to scrape data from a web canvas?
I would like to scrape all values from the blue/orange line graph, that's the photo:
[image]

I have tried nothing, i've just can't find anything about it.
To make that graph open, you should click at the curve line plus button at the top, right after IBOV and then place at the search "RSI Estocástico"

Comment: Could imagine using something like `Selenium` to emulate browser and mouse position... but I'd imagine there's a better source of stock prices out there.

Answer (score 0):

Tradingview has a good public api, but maybe not for RSI indicator. If it has no, you need to fetch the chart data with the API, and you could calculate RSI by you own.

Comment: i've tried the calculation, but it gives some error, some bad approximations to the thing i need to do.

Comment: I need the exact value

Comment: By the way, do u know the API name?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't used it.